# docker get rid of every image of specific type except latest

Tags: docker

I'd like to automize the removal of docker layers which just aren't used anymore since docker loves to gobble up hard drive space.

So I'd like a script that would remove all images of a specific type except the last used image. So I'm guessing there

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mop-test-image      b4ffabd                a16fc65f4d19        10 minutes ago      1.95GB
mop-test-image      e7e5b14                7971bf4c01ce        17 minutes ago      1.95GB
mop-test-image      4325d4e                d6a3377f609a        32 minutes ago      1.95GB
```

So in the following list above I'd like all the images removed except for the one created 10 minutes ago.

I use this currently to remove all of the images of that kind, so it needs tweaking:

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep test- | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
```

Comment: if only the last image is in use, you can easily use `docker image prune -f`

Comment: @LinPy The last image is *not* in use! (all containers are removed immediately after they do their job)

Comment: then use `until` parameter

Comment: @karl-morrison does your image tag have any patterns like image-name:v1 or v2. SO the pattern here is v*

Comment: @mchawre Unforunetly no, our tags are based on git commit short-hashs. So we can map images to specific commits.

Answer (score 3):

using `until`:

```
docker image prune -a --force --filter "until=10m"
```

delete all images older than 10 mins

you can also use `--filter` using `repository`  or `ID` to select only some types of the images

see more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)

Comment: Awesome! Just one thing though, I can't prune *all* images. I need to select specific ones! Is there a filter parameter for this perhaps?

Comment: yes you can use `--filter`and you can use the repository then I think or ID

Comment: Ah yes I agree! I will upvote anyway since this might help someone else, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

If you are more interested in a solution that won’t require knowledge of how old the cutoff date is, the following script should do it.

It simply loops over the docker images, stores the image name in the lookup if it hasn’t been seen before, otherwise deletes it.

**Update**
I've written two versions, the newer improved version is for zsh, the older one below for bash.

**DANGER** I use `docker system prune -f` which will forcefully delete dangling images and may have undesired side-effects. Use with caution.

---

### BASH

https://gist.github.com/Mazyod/da92f8cda1783baa017f9323375c159c

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "Script for cleaning up Docker images"

# First, we grab a list of all images
docker_images=$(docker images --format "{{.ID}}|{{.Repository}}|{{.Tag}}")

# prepare a image name lookup
declare -A image_names

# Then, we loop through the list
while read -r line; do
    # We split the line into an array
    IFS='|' read -r -a array <<< "$line"

    # We grab the image ID
    image_id=${array[0]}

    # We grab the image name
    image_name=${array[1]}

    # We grab the image tag
    image_tag=${array[2]}

    # We check if the image_name has already been saved in image_names
    if [[ -z "${image_names[$image_name]}" ]]; then
        # If not, we save it
        echo "Keeping ${image_name}:${image_tag}"
        image_names[$image_name]=$image_id
    else
        # If yes, we remove the image
        echo "Removing ${image_name}:${image_tag}"
        docker rmi "${image_name}:${image_tag}"
    fi
done <<< "$docker_images"
```

---

### ZSH

https://gist.github.com/Mazyod/da92f8cda1783baa017f9323375c159c#file-zsh-delete-older-docker-image-tags-sh

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
# Next time this breaks, port it to python!

echo "Script for cleaning up Docker images"
echo "===================================="
echo ""

# Run prune before deleting tags to clean up problematic <none> tags
echo "Pruning images"
echo "--------------"
docker system prune -f
echo ""


echo "Remove older tags for images"
echo "----------------------------"
# First, we grab a list of all images
docker_images=$(docker images --format "{{.ID}}|{{.Repository}}|{{.Tag}}")

# prepare a image lookups
declare -A image_ids
declare -A image_tags

# Then, we loop through the list
while read -r line; do
    # We split the line into an array
    IFS='|' read -r -A array <<< "$line"

    # We grab the image ID
    image_id=${array[1]}

    # We grab the image name
    image_name=${array[2]}

    # We grab the image tag
    image_tag=${array[3]}

    # We check if the image_name has already been saved in image_ids
    if [[ -z "${image_ids[$image_name]}" ]]; then
        # If not, we save it
        echo "Keeping ${image_name}:${image_tag}"
        image_ids[$image_name]=$image_id
        image_tags[$image_name]=$image_tag
    # If yes, we check if image_id matches and image_tag is older
    elif [[ "${image_ids[$image_name]}" == "$image_id" ]] && [[ "${image_tags[$image_name]}" < "$image_tag" ]]; then
        # If yes, we delete the saved image
        echo "Found newer tag for ${image_name}:${image_tag}"
        echo "Deleting ${image_name}:${image_tags[$image_name]}"
        docker rmi "${image_name}:${image_tags[$image_name]}" || true  # ignore errors (e.g. if image is in use)
        # And we save the new image
        image_tags[$image_name]=$image_tag
    else
        # If yes, we remove the image
        echo "Deleting ${image_name}:${image_tag}"
        docker rmi "${image_name}:${image_tag}" || true  # ignore errors (e.g. if image is in use)
    fi
done <<< "$docker_images"
echo ""

# Run prune after deleting tags to clean up layers and cache
echo "Pruning images (again)"
echo "----------------------"
docker system prune -f
echo ""
```

Comment: I've had an issue with this approach: 
read: bad option: -a

Comment: @OverclockedSkid are you perhaps using an older version of bash, or another shell?

Comment: Ohh, definitively, I'm using zsh (but recent version)

Comment: @OverclockedSkid I added zsh version here https://gist.github.com/Mazyod/da92f8cda1783baa017f9323375c159c#file-zsh-delete-older-docker-image-tags-sh